# Debian - default gateway per ip or interface

Tags: network-access

Got 4 network interfaces...

1. Fiber 300mbps (only for internal communication between servers)
2. GSM Modem (PPP, wvDial, GSM Network #1)
3. Other GSM Modem (PPP, wvDial, GSM Network #2)
4. Yet another GSM Modem (PPP, wvDial, GSM Network #3)

By default, everything uses fiber connection, but I would like some applications to force to use GSM networks. So I am using `LD_PRELOAD` param with [ip binding script](http://www.ryde.net/code/bind.c.txt).

That partially works... you can set `BIND_ADDR` and application uses it, but the problem is with `default gateway` that is set to fiber network... so binding ip from GSM nerwork simply effects in lack of connection at all.

How do I make it right, so after binding to ip of interfece 2 or 3 or 4, it would use gateway of that interface? Please note, that IP addresses are variable!

**Happy New Year!**

Comment: Are you using this as a router for other devices connecting to it, or is the routing strictly from the Debian box? Specific routes will be used before any default route, so you should probably use specific routes for the fiber rather than a default route.

Comment: "Policy based routing" You will have to setup routes and rules that look at the source address instead of the destination.  Such OS SPECIFIC configuration is off-topic. (ask on one of the many linux networking forums. Or any of the various HOW-TO's that already explain how. I'll warn you: it's a fragile complicated mess.)

Comment: @Ron Maupin It's standalone. Doesn't need to share any connection anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of approaches to this.

One approach is to route based on source address. There is an example at http://www.lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html#LARTC.RPDB.SIMPLE (the example uses a remote source address but I don't belive there is any difference here between local and remote source addreses). You can then use this in conjuction with the script you have to force applications to bind to a particular local address.

The other approach is to use network namespaces. This allows you to isolate applications with seperate copies of the network stack. However it is still a fairly new feature and when I tried it I had trouble making it work.

Comment: First solution is a bit annoying in usage, as on every GSM connection, new IP is being assigned - would make routing tables really messy... could you please tell me something more about second solution? You mean something like `ip netns add mynamespace;(... configuration of namespace...); ip netns exec mynamespace something`? or it's totally different solution :D